# Angular Material css aligning issue

Tags: css, angularjs, material-design, angularjs-material

Currently, when the browser's width become smaller... my icons end up floating to the left.

[image]

How can I have them centered horizontally? Any help will be appreciated.

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="sandbox">
  <div layout="column" layout-fill>
    <div class="flexbox-parent">
      <div layout="row" layout-align="center center" style="height: 600px;">
        <div id="icons">
          <i class="fa fa-facebook fa-5x circle-icon"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-facebook fa-5x circle-icon"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-facebook fa-5x circle-icon"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#icons i {
  color: #fff;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.circle-icon {
  background: #3b5998;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 30px;
}
```

I have tried using `layout-align="center center"` on `#icons`

**[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/gbmduwem/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is a Angular Material class for that, but you can achieve this by manually setting `text-align: center` on your wrapper. In four example you'd go like this:

```
#icons {
  text-align: center;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gbmduwem/1/)

Comment: Ah! Simple solution... Not sure what I was thinking

Comment: Glad I could help. As mentioned, there still be a better solution. I've also took a look into the docs but couldn't find any properly working solution so far. Maybe that's the real deal here.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any CSS - [CodePen](http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/vXqQqR)

Markup

```
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl" ng-cloak="" ng-app="MyApp" layout-fill layout="column" layout-align="center center">
  <div layout="column">
    <i class="fa fa-facebook fa-5x circle-icon"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-facebook fa-5x circle-icon"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-facebook fa-5x circle-icon"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```